# Installed Magento 1.9.4 via Softaculous; Any patches needed?

Tags: patches, installation, magento-1.9.4.0

```
Magento 1.9.4
```

I just did a fresh install of Magento 1.9.4 via the Softaculous app in the Cpanel.

Are there any patches that I need to install next or can I proceed with installing a theme and extensions that I need?

Comment: If this is a public install, you can use magereport.com to check

Comment: If any patch has been introduced after launching a Magento version, you have to install it explicitly. So please check for the patches which have been added by Magento after the launch of Magento 1.9.4.

Comment: I did the scan and it looks alright. I found this information on the web: Magento 1.9.4 was released on November 28 and contains the security patch SUPEE-10975 with 30 fixes for multiple critical security issues. Besides the fixed vulnerabilities, support for PHP 7.2 was added and some bugs were solved.